# Webservice toolkits in Java that can interface with WCF

Tags: c#, java, wcf, web-services, axis

We've got some problems with an external company trying in integrate into a WCF service we expose and they are a Java shop. I was wondering if there are more than one toolkit that they can try to solve their issues and would like a list to suggest to them but I'm not familiar with the Java world at all.

Essentially they've got some memory leak (apparently!) but they are very sketchy in the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft and Sun [worked together](https://wsit.dev.java.net/) to ensure that their latest web services toolkits worked with each other. Sun's java implementation is [Metro](https://metro.dev.java.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Are they using Axis, if you are presenting a standard webservice to them? Or are you presenting a custom REST service that they have had to do more manual coding for (HTTPClient, XML generators/parsers, etc)?

Comment: No, standard SOAP based Contract with WS-Security + mutual authentication on top. THey have it working, they are just getting occasional reliabiltiy problems.

What other tool kits are there?

Comment: Kieran: you should edit your question to include this information as opposed to entering it in the comments of this answer.

Comment: @Craig, Granted, but it doesnt really have anything to do with the question and I want to avoid switching the focus to this instead of what I am actually asking!

Comment: @Kieran - you should put this info in the question as an update. Otherwise you could have 10 answers each with 1-3 comments and we'd all have scan these just to find out that indeed it's std SOAP + WS-Security. You're likely to get a better far response. Trust me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you're using a normal web service binding and nothing else.  I admit though over the years getting java and .net web services to play nicely is no mean feat.  A memory leak by the way, would have nothing to do with calling your web service and everything to do with the way the external company is managing their memory.  You're not executing anything on their servers after all :-)

Comment: Oh I know Phil, its not my problem - I'm just trying to find a solution for them and they reckon its osmething to do with an exception (application originating and quite reasonable) being thrown. Brilliant isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this successfully with [Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/).  It was actually pretty straight forward, using the Eclipse plugins.